# How to pass data with data class from a dialog fragment to another fragment with interface in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, interface

I have a fragment that hosts a dialog fragment that contains EditText Fields. When a button is clicked in the dialog fragment, the data from the EditText fields should be passed to the host.

This is what I have been working with:

The host fragment

```
class MeasurementsFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment(), RecyclerClickListener {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        /*Initialize Views*/
        display = binding.measurementsFragmentTestingTextView
        addMeasurementFab = binding.clientMeasurementFragmentAddMeasurementFab
        addMeasurementFab.setOnClickListener {
            AddMeasurementDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "Dialog tag")
        }

    override fun onItemClicked1(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel) {
        EditMeasurementDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "Dialog tag")
    }

    override fun onItemClicked2(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Position 2 was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

The dialog fragment

```
class AddMeasurementDialogFragment : DialogFragment(){
    private var _binding: AddMeasurementDialogFragmentBinding? = null
    private lateinit var addMeasurementButton: Button
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        addMeasurementButton = binding.addMeasurementFragmentAddMeasurementButton
        addMeasurementButton.setOnClickListener {
            val measurementName = binding.addAddressFragmentMeasurementNameEditText.text.toString()
            val measurement = binding.addMeasurementFragmentAddMeasureEditText.text.toString().toBigDecimal()
            val action = AddMeasurementDialogFragmentDirections.actionAddMeasurementFragmentToMeasurementsFragment(
                DressMeasurementModel(measurementName, measurement)
            )
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    interface DialogFragmentInterface {
        fun passDataMethod(data:DressMeasurementModel)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use listener for communicating between Fragments and Activities. The newer approach is to use [FragmentResult](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#kotlin) API

Set result when user click in your child fragment:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val editTextString = "..." // Get string from EditText
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResult("keyClicked", bundleOf("bundleKey" to editTextString))
}
```

In your parent fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Set the listener to get notified when clicked
    // And retrieve the EditText data
    childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("keyClicked") { key, bundle ->
        val editTextString = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
        // Do something with the string
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ananta Raha, But i now have another issue. When i tried to work with the result like this

`

        childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("keyClicked", requireActivity()) { key, bundle ->
            val editTextString = bundle.getString("bundleKey") as DressMeasurementModel
            // Do something with the string
            currentList.add(0, editTextString)

        }
`

It said this `This cast can never succed`

I'm working with data class in the bundle.

Comment: No need to cast as DressMeasurementModel. You can simply put the two strings in the bundle with two different keys, and retrieve them later separately in your parent fragment. If you still want to pass the DressMeasurementModel object in this way, you have to make it Parcelable.

Comment: Yes, i later figured it out. I was using Parcelable in the data class so i used getParcelable()  instead of getString(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html) to make your task easier.

**For example:**

```
class AddMeasurementDialogFragment(
    private var onClick : (model: DressMeasurementModel) -> Unit = {  }
): DialogFragment(){---}
```

and where the click is handled you just need to call`onClick() and pass data to it`

```
onClick(dressMeasurementModel)
```

Then when you are getting instance of this class you just need to use that onClick :

```
 val dialog= AddMeasurementDialogFragment()
          { selectedDressModel ->
           // HERE YOU GET THE DATA AND FURTHER CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
          }
```